# Converting ArcGIS date value to string reading in mm/dd/yyyy format using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, file-geodatabase, date

I am writing an arcpy tool script in ArcGIS 10.0.  In a fGDB feature class, I have a Date type field.  I gather that the values in the Date field are stored as long integer dates, but they display in mm/dd/yyy format in the table.  What I want to do is capture the integer date value as a string showing the date in mm/dd/yyyy format.  How do I go about this?

There are many examples of how to convert a date/time string to a date object/value but not vice versa.  I am appending features from a feature class with many fields, including a date field, into a standard-schema fc (which I can't change) that has few fields.  To save a lot of the technical attributes in the input, I must dump it all into a catch-all, user-controlled text field that is defined in the target.  The date data from the input is one of those pieces of data I need to save, hence the need to convert the date to a string.

There is likely a fairly easy solution I'm missing, but at the moment I am at a loss.  I appreciate any help that comes my way.

Comment: It's been months, have you solved your problem?

Comment: @R.K. - I'm very sorry to have left those interested hanging on this one.  I lost track.  Anyway, yes, blah238's answer below worked just fine.  The particular script I was working on was subsequently changed in a way that eliminated the need for the date conversion, but I have used this solution multiple times since in other scripts.  Thanks, R.K., for asking, and thank you blah238 for you help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GP cursors read date values as [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects, so you can use [`datetime.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format it as you like, or [`datetime.ctime()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.ctime) to format it as the default format (`%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y`).

Here's an example using `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime
fc = r"C:\GISData\test.gdb\atlantic_hurricanes_2000"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    datetimeVal = row.getValue("Date_Time")
    formattedTime = datetime.strftime(datetimeVal, "%m/%d/%Y")
    print formattedTime
```

For the meanings of the various time formatting codes see [strftime behavior](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior).