# How to retrieve the year from a date format?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, python-2.7

I'm attempting to retrieve the year from the following date format: 1/1/1988
I've tried the following but it does not work str(1/1/1988)[4:] and I've also tried str(1//1//1988)[4:]

Comment: In what context? A Python script? Can you post it? In field calculator?

Comment: Can we assume that this is coming from a field of "date" type?

Comment: I'm using a Python update cursor to reference a date field which has dates in the following format 5/1/1988 and update another field with only the year of the date 5/1/1988 which in this case is 1988.  @JasonScheirer

Comment: @RyanDalton you're right.

Comment: What ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using?  Are you using the Data Access module? Can you post a code snippet to show how you are using a "Python update cursor to reference a date field"?  Please edit these details into your question so that a potential answerer only needs to read that to get the full picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sort of question is better answered in **[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)** but the answer is straight-forward enough so I'll give you a hint here.

Your date is not a date as far as Python is concerned but a division sum - which is the main reason why it doesn't work.  Your code also won't give you the last four digits.  You need '[-4:]' (yours gives everything except the first four characters of the string).  You need to cast your date as a date using the datetime module.  Then to convert a properly cast date as a string in the format you have in your original post you call `myDate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")[-4:]`

Comment: I've not dealt with dates all that much in Python, how would I cast my date as a date using the datetime module

Comment: If the date is coming back as a Python `datetime` object (which if the field is of type date it will be - see @blah238 's answer to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/in-an-arcpy-script-how-do-i-convert-arcgis-date-value-to-a-string-reading-in-mm?rq=1)) then it will have a [`year` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year)